# How can I vertically adjust my exterior door hinges?

Tags: doors, hinges, socket

I cannot figure out how to vertically adjust these hinges in my glass door. The door is not closing properly, but only on the top side, and it creaks with strong winds, and even partially opens from the top.

I fixed it temporarily by lifting the door from the bottom hinge a bit, where an allen hexagonal key was enough, and I figured I should give some leeway to the top one as well, but it's trickier here.

I tried with a socket wrench but the "flaps" covering the metal part won't let the header go in, and it doesn't even look like an hexagonal head.

Any idea how this could be adjusted?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: That's not an Allen screw, it's a Torx screw.  Does that odd looking shaft on the bottom with the flat push in at all?

Comment: With the Torx screw you mean the horizontal screw that goes into the door? I figured that's just affixing the hinge to the frame. The shaft that you mention doesn't push in. It is what I think should be turned to adjust vertically.

Comment: There are two of those shafts, with another one on top, but it's hard to get a pic of it because of lack of space. Edit:added a third pic from the top.

Comment: What makes you think these hinges have a vertical adjustment feature (most don't)? Are these "self-closing" hinges, like spring operated (I ask because that pin looks like a spring-tension adjuster)?

Comment: @JimmyFix-it the bottom hinge could be adjusted, so I assumed this one would be adjustable as well.

Comment: @CarlosRomero how is the bottom hinge adjusted?

Comment: @Huesmann I added a fourth pic with the bottom hinge. It's adjusted with an allen hex key. I am starting to think it's the only adjustable one, with the top one having a spring inside like it was mentioned above...

Comment: Ah, yes, finally an actual Allen head fastener!